# Python beautifulsoup: Get a placeholder from img src

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, placeholder, src

With the help of BeautifulSoup I try to read the image address of an image from a homepage.
In the page source text I see the URL of the image.
But if I try to read the address with the command `find_all` from BeautifulSoup I only get a placeholder for the image URL.

The URL from the image is structured as follows:

`<a href="Young-Justice-(2019)/Young-Justice-(2019)-Issue-11/3"><br /><img src="mangas/Young Justice (2019)/Young Justice (2019) Issue 11/cw002.jpg" alt="" width="1200" height="1846" class="picture" /></a>`

In BeautifulSoup i get this:

`<img 0="" alt="" class="picture" height="" src="/pics/placeholder2.jpg" width=""/>]`

I hope anybody can give me a tip or why i get a placeholder instead the original image url.

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError


def getimageurl(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BS(response.text, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

        for a in data:
            t = a.find_all('img', attrs={'class': 'picture'})
            print(t)
    except ConnectionError:
        print('Cant open url: {0}'.format(url))
```

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: Url: https://comicpunch.net/reader/Young-Justice-(2019)/Young-Justice-(2019)-Issue-11/2

Comment: so , your goal is just get '/pics/placeholder2.jpg' ??

Comment: I can't replicate your problem; my `t` output is `<img alt="" class="picture" height="1846" src="mangas/Young Justice (2019)/Young Justice (2019) Issue 11/cw002.jpg" width="1200"/>`.

Comment: Sorry guys it was my mistake. :-( Thank for youre time and help.